# odoo (V11) add a new search button to control panel view

Tags: html, xml, odoo, odoo-11

I want to add a new search button to the odoo control panel view. I am using odoo V11 and the screenshot of the view is pasted here so you can understand what I am talking about. I want to add this button next to the search box indicated as a black circle in the image. The new search box will provide Spatial data search function. That is why I want to create a new search button instead of using the existing search options.
Thanks

[odoo control panel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSGBw.png)

Comment: It is about programming. Odoo uses XML/template to generate the view and choose which JS file to load. The problem is that the odoo email list is not very active. That is why I ask here.

Comment: @JerryZhang Have you used the Developer Mode at all? It allows you to see a lot of additional information, including which views, actions, etc. are used to load whichever view you are looking at. It can be enabled in the middle/bottom right section of the **Settings** app and it adds a small "bug" icon into the top-right side of the navigation menu (near your user name). You'll probably want to use the "Edit Form View" option in that menu.

Comment: I just find out base.xml controls the control panel view. But I will do what you said first because possibly it is an easy approach. Thanks

Comment: I always use the browser developer apps to inspect the html code and then use used classes as search term to find the templates in the code base.

Comment: @CZoellner That is exactly what I did to find out base.xml actually determines the control panel view. I want to add a new search button next to the search box. That is why I want to change the view. Thanks

Comment: So you've already found the template, but don't know how to extend/change it? Maybe you should change your question then ;-)

Comment: I just found the view about 10 minutes ago and I am still trying to change it:)

Comment: Don't forget to answer yourself, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would not complicate myself adding that button, just use the existing search box to enter the data to search and add a new option "Spatial data" to the menu shown when you enter text. That is added with xml, similar to this example taken from the bank views:

```
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
     <search string="Bank Accounts">
         <field name="bank_name" filter_domain="['|', ('bank_name','ilike',self), ('acc_number','ilike',self)]" string="Bank Name"/>
         <field name="company_id" invisible="context.get('company_hide', True)"/>
         <field name="partner_id"/>
     </search>
  </field>
```

You may also need to do some coding in the .py files if it is not enough with just the domain filter, in that case override the name_search method of the model. You have many examples of that in the Odoo code itself.

Comment: This is also a solution. It is easier than adding that button. I definitively need to add some python code. Thanks